# Detecting Vowels vs Consonants In Python

Tags: python, string, conditional-statements

What silly mistake am I making here that is preventing me from determining that the first letter of user input is a consonant? No matter what I enter, it allows evaluates that the first letter is a vowel.

```
original = raw_input('Enter a word:')
word = original.lower()
first = word[0]

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    if first == "a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u":
        print "vowel"
    else:
        print "consonant"
else:
    print "empty"
```

Comment: Another approach would be use to use the startswith() method. Assigning the word to the variable `first` you could then do the comparison: first == first.startswith(('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')); if `True` then you would know that this word does not begin with a consonant.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Change:

```
if first == "a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u":
```

to:

```
if first in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):  #or `if first in 'aeiou'`
```

`first == "a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u"` is always `True` because it is evaluated as

`(first == "a") or ("e") or ("i") or ("o") or ("u")`, as an non-empty string is always True so this gets evaluated to True.

```
>>> bool('e')
True
```

Comment: Or since this is all single letters, `if first in 'aeiou':`.

Answer (score 9):

What you are doing in your `if` statement is checking if `first == "a"` is true and then if `"e"` is true, which it always is, so the if statement always evaluates to true.
What you should do instead is:

```
if first == "a" or first == "e" ...
```

or better yet:

```
if first in "aeiou":
```

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that `first == "a" or "e"` is being evaluated as `(first == "a") or "e"`, so you're always going to get `'e'`, which is a `True` statement, causing `"vowel"` to be printed. An alternative is to do:

```
original = raw_input('Enter a word:')
word = original.lower()
first = word[0]

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    if first in 'aeiou':
        print "vowel"
    else:
        print "consonant"
else:
    print "empty"
```