# Counting a string python

Tags: python, counting

I'm a bit confused with the counting of a string that I would enter manually. I am basically trying to count the number of words and the number of characters without spaces. Also if it would be possible, who can help with counting the vowels?

This is all I have so far:

```
vowels = [ 'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']
constants= ['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z']

s= input ('Enter a Sentence: ')

print ('Your sentence is:', s)

print ('Number of Characters', len(s));

print ('Number of Vowels', s);
```

Comment: this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226110/detecting-vowels-vs-consonants-in-python

Answer (score 2):

```
s = input("Enter a sentence: ")

word_count = len(s.split()) # count the words with split
char_count = len(s.replace(' ', '')) # count the chars having replaced spaces with ''
vowel_count = sum(1 for c in s if c.lower() in ['a','e','i','o','u']) # sum 1 for each vowel
```

**more info:**

on `str.split`: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm

on `sum`:

```
sum(sequence[, start]) -> value

Return the sum of a sequence of numbers (NOT strings) plus the value
of parameter 'start' (which defaults to 0).  When the sequence is
empty, return start.
```

on `str.replace`: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

Comment: If this solution solved your issue, please consider accepting it as the official answer(the tick mark next to the votes number)

Answer (score 0):

```
vowels = [ 'a','e','i','o','u']
sentence = "Our World is a better place"
count_vow = 0
count_con = 0
for x in sentence:
    if x.isalpha():
        if x.lower() in vowels:
            count_vow += 1
        else:
            count_con += 1
print count_vow,count_con
```

Comment: You have a type on line 8, should be `count_vow` += 1

Comment: ahh sorry it was a typing mistake

Answer (score 0):

For vowels:

Basic way of doing this is using a for loop and checking each character if they exist in a string, list or other sequence (vowels in this case). I think this is the way you should first learn to do it since it's easiest for beginner to understand.

```
def how_many_vowels(text):
  vowels = 'aeiou'
  vowel_count = 0
  for char in text:
    if char.lower() in vowels:
      vowel_count += 1
  return vowel_count
```

Once you learn more and figure out [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), you could do it

```
def how_many_vowels(text):
  vowels = 'aeiou'
  vowels_in_text = [ch for ch in text if ch.lower() in vowels]
  return len(vowels_in_text)
```

or as @totem wrote, using sum

```
def how_many_vowels(text):
  vowels = 'aeiou'
  vowel_count = sum(1 for ch in text if ch.lower() in vowels)
  return vowel_count
```