# Python Counting Vowels

Tags: python, python-3.x, counting

I have started on a program to count vowels and have seemed to be getting nowhere. I need to count vowels from a string and then display the vowels. I need to do this by storing the number of occurrences in variables. Like this :

```
    a = 0
    b = 0
    ....

    then print the lowest.
```

Current code (its not that much ):

```
string = str(input("please input a string:  "))
edit= ''.join(string)


print(edit)
```

I have tried a number of methods just by my self and don't seem to get anywhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting Vowels vs Consonants In Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226110/detecting-vowels-vs-consonants-in-python)

Comment: print the lowest what? count or word based on the count?

Comment: print the lowest count

Answer (score 3):

You could use a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> example = 'this is an example string'
>>> vowel_counts = {c: example.count(c) for c in 'aeoiu'}
>>> vowel_counts
{'i': 2, 'o': 0, 'e': 5, 'u': 0, 'a': 2}
```

Then finding the minimum, maximum etc. is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a="hello how are you"
>>> vowel_count = dict.fromkeys('aeiou',0)
>>> vowel_count 
{'a': 0, 'i': 0, 'e': 0, 'u': 0, 'o': 0}
>>> for x in 'aeiou':
...     vowel_count[x]=a.count(x)
... 
>>> vowel_count 
{'a': 1, 'i': 0, 'e': 2, 'u': 1, 'o': 3}
```

now from here you can print low nd max

Answer (score 0):

You can use **dictionary** for this problem. Iterate over each character and if the character is a **vowel**, put it in **dictionary** with count `0` and increment its count by `1`, and for every next occurrence keep incrementing the count.

```
>>> string = str(input("please input a string:  "))
please input a string:  'Hello how are you'
>>> dt={}   # initialize dictionary
>>> for i in string:  # iterate over each character
...    if i in ['a','e','i','o','u']:   # if vowel
...       dt.setdefault(i,0)  # at first occurrence set count to 0
...       dt[i]+=1   # increment count by 1
...
>>> dt
{'a': 1, 'u': 1, 'e': 2, 'o': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word = input('Enter Your word : ')
vowel = 'aeiou'
vowel_counter = {}

for char in word:
  if char in vowel:
    vowel_counter[char] = vowel_counter.setdefault(char,0)+1

sorted_result = sorted(vowel_counter.items(), reverse=True,key=lambda x : x[1])

for key,val in sorted_result:
  print(key,val)
```