# How I write a function in python that determines whether a word has no vowels?

Tags: python

How I write a function "noVowel" in python that determines whether a word has no vowels?

In my case, "y" is not a vowel.

For example, I want the function to return True if the word is something like "My" and to return false if the word is something like "banana".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting Vowels vs Consonants In Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226110/detecting-vowels-vs-consonants-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
any(vowel in word for vowel in 'aeiou')
```

Where `word` is the word you're searching.

Broken down:

`any` returns `True` if any of the values it checks are `True` returns `False` otherwise

`for vowel in 'aeiou'` sets the value of `vowel` to a, then e, then i, etc.

`vowel in word` checks if the string `word` contains vowel.

If you don't understand why this works, I suggest you look up generator expressions, they are a very valuable tool.

EDIT

Oops, this returns `True` if there is a vowel and `False` otherwise.  To do it the other way, you could

```
all(vowel not in word for vowel in 'aeiou')
```

or

```
not any(vowel in word for vowel in 'aeiou')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def noVowel(word):
    vowels = 'aeiou' ## defining the vowels in the English alphabet
    hasVowel= False ## Boolean variable that tells us if there is any vowel
    for i in range(0,len(word)): ## Iterate through the word
        if word[i] in vowels: ## If the char at the current index is a vowel, break out of the loop
            hasVowel = True
            break
        else: ## if not, keep the boolean false
            hasVowel=False
    ## check the boolean, and return accordingly
    if hasVowel: 
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Hope it helps!