# I am trying to create a function that inputs a string and returns the number of vowels in the string that are in an odd position within the string

Tags: python-3.x

I have a homework assignment to create this function.
Here is my code:

```
def countVowelsOdd(n):
    length = len(n)
    count = 0
    for i in range(length): 
        if i % 2 != 0:
            if n[i] == "a" or "A" or "e" or "E" or "i" or "I" or "o" or "O" or "u" or "U":
                count = count + 1
    return count
```

Here is the output vs the expected output for this function: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R419V.png

Comment: // , What research have you done already? Could you put your output in a text format, rather than an image that we might not be able to copy?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to account for vowels in odd positions do:

```
for i in range(1, length, 2):
```

Check [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) docs where it says that you can pass `start`, `stop` and `step` arguments. Then range will go from 1, 3, 5, ..., to `length-1`.

You could also do

```
if n[i].lower() in "aeiou":
```

As a shorter expression for checking if letter is vowel. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20226110/10322652) question as an example.

Comment: (1) `range` will not go until `length`, the stop parameter is *exclusive*, (2) `x in ['aeiou']` will only be true if `x` is exactly the string `'aeiou'`, not if `x` is one of the characters a, e, i, o, u.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You're right. Just edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your only problem is the line

```
if n[i] == "a" or "A" or "e" or "E" or "i" or "I" or "o" or "O" or "u" or "U":
```

it either needs to be

```
if n[i] == "a" or n[i] == "A" or n[i] == "e" or n[i] == "E" or n[i] == "i" or n[i] == "I" or n[i] == "o" or n[i] == "O" or n[i] == "u" or n[i] == "U":
```

or you can also use

```
if n[i] in "aAeEiIoOuU":
```

which I actually prefer. However this line can still get improved

```
if n[i].upper() in "AEIOU":
```