# From a string, how do you return only the words that don't begin with a vowel?

Tags: python, string

I have a string E.g. "A dog is a good pet"

I would like to be able to return only the words that begin with a consonant. ["dog", "good", "pet"] as a list

```
def consonant_first(newstr):
    for char in newstr.split():
        if char[0] in newstr.split() ==  vowels1:
            return newstr.split() 
print(newstr)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting Vowels vs Consonants In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226110/detecting-vowels-vs-consonants-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

Just test the first letter in a list comprehension:

```
s = "A dog is a good pet"

def consonant_first(newstr):
    return [word for word in s.split() if  word[0].lower() not in 'aeiou']

print(consonant_first(s))
```

Make sure to test against all cases so you catch the `A`.

**result:**

```
['dog', 'good', 'pet']
```

Comment: How would this work if I had to write it as a function def consonant_first():

Comment: It takes the entire sentence.

Comment: @Trevor713 see the edit — you can just wrap it in a def: and return the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses iterators in case you're planning on processing very large amount of text:

```py
import re

def find_consonant_words(text: str):
    vowels = set("aeiou")

    for m in re.finditer('\S+', text):
        w = m.group(0)
        if w[0].lower() not in vowels:
            yield w

string = "A very long text: a dog is a good pet"

for w in find_consonant_words(string):
    print(w)

# get it all as a list
consonant_words = list(find_consonant_words(string))
print(consonant_words)
```

output:

```
very
long
text:
dog
good
pet
['very', 'long', 'text:', 'dog', 'good', 'pet']
```